# Is it possible to disable monitor mode in Bash on invocation

Tags: bash

Monitor mode can be disabled inside of Bash using `set +m`. I would like to know whether it is possible to do this using Bash's arguments on invocation. That is, something like:

```
bash +o monitor
```

or perhaps:

```
bash +m
```

I have been looking at Bash's manpage for a while now and it is starting to seem like this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks impossible to disable monitor mode for an interactive bash session with command-line options/arguments at invocation time, unless you cheat. I determined this by digging into the source code, primarily the files [shell.c](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c) and [jobs.c](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/flags.c). I cloned the repo locally with `git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/bash.git` so that it was easier to search.

It's impossible to disable monitor mode at invocation time because the bash startup sequence enables monitor mode *after* processing the various options/arguments. Even if you invoke `bash +o monitor`, where bash will *temporarily* set the option in the [`parse_shell_options`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c#n870) function, it later calls a function named [`set_job_control`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c#n4972) (again, when in interactive mode) which sets the global variable "job_control" to true (the value of the "interactive" argument).

Note that the potential `+O` shopt route via the `run_shopt_alist` function is a dead-end, despite the interactive `shopt` command being able to disable monitor mode with `shopt -o -u monitor`, because monitor mode is not a native shopt option.

The cheat method relies on an external file; you'd create an alternative bashrc file containing `set +m` (and optionally sourcing your real ~/.bashrc), then invoke bash as:

```bsh
bash --rcfile /path/to/that/alternate_bashrc_file
```

This works because the rcfile parsing is done (with the [`run_startup_files`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c#n1098) function) *after* `set_job_control` is called, so it's able to finally set the shell option.

Comment: I guess the catch with this cheat method is that monitor mode is still initially enabled in interactive mode but then automatically disabled by the alternative bashrc file, right?

Comment: That's right; monitor mode is disabled by the time you have a prompt.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set monitor to disabled:

```
$ bash +o monitor -c 'shopt -op monitor'
shopt +o monitor
```

But **only** for non-interactive shells (scripts, one liners (-c) for example).

For interactive shells, even if you try, monitor is re-enabled:

```
$ bash +o monitor
~/.bashrc sourced
$ shopt -op monitor
set -o monitor
$ exit
```

But, as the `bashrc` file is loaded (as shown above), you can include a line to disable it.